# Auto fill column based off values in another pandas

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I am trying to fill a separate column based off values in another. For the `df` below I want to fill `['Assign']` with `'C1'` when `['Code'] == 'A'` and `'C2' when ['Code'] == 'B'`. Everything else I like to fill with `np.nan`

import pandas as pd

```
d = ({
    'Place' : ['Home','Away','Work','Home','Shops','Park','Cafe','Shops','Away','Home','Cafe','Work','Park'],  
    'Code' : ['A','A','A','A','C','B','B','C','A','A','B','A','B'],            
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have attempted this but the values are incorrect.

```
df['Assign'] = df['Code'].where((df['Code'] == 'A'), ['C1'])
df['Assign'] = df['Code'].where((df['Code'] == 'B'), ['C2'])
```

I'm hoping to output this:

```
    Place Code Assign
0    Home    A     C1
1    Away    A     C1
2    Work    A     C1
3    Home    A     C1
4   Shops    C     
5    Park    B     C2
6    Cafe    B     C2
7   Shops    C     
8    Away    A     C1
9    Home    A     C1
10   Cafe    B     C2
11   Work    A     C1
12   Park    B     C2
```

Comment: Is it possible that `Code` contains neither `A` or `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` with a dictionaries `get` method and a default value

```
m = lambda x: dict(A='C1', B='C2').get(x, '')
df.assign(Assign=df.Code.map(m))

    Place Code Assign
0    Home    A     C1
1    Away    A     C1
2    Work    A     C1
3    Home    A     C1
4   Shops    C       
5    Park    B     C2
6    Cafe    B     C2
7   Shops    C       
8    Away    A     C1
9    Home    A     C1
10   Cafe    B     C2
11   Work    A     C1
12   Park    B     C2
```

---

Or `fillna`

```
m = dict(A='C1', B='C2')
df.assign(Assign=df.Code.map(m).fillna(''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df['Assign'] = np.where(df['Code']=='A','C1','C2')
```

As per recent change in question the solution is:

```
df['Assign'] = np.where(df['Code']=='A','C1',np.where(df['Code']=='B','C2',''))
```

If you want null value if when `df['Code']=='C'` use:

```
df['Assign'] = np.where(df['Code']=='A','C1',np.where(df['Code']=='B','C2',None))
```

None is a null value for strings.